# webpack-merge merge is not a function

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I have trying to add react in the shopify theme. So configured react, webpack, babel manually.
Webpack.dev.js

```
const merge  = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require("./webpack.common.js")

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  watch: true
})
```

But I am getting error, merge is not a function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In a new version of [webpack-merge,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) It is imported like below.

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
```

Answer (score 13):

As from version 5 of [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge), the merge function is now named export instead of a default export.

**Before version 5**

```js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
```

**From version 5**

```js
const merge = require('webpack-merge').merge;
```

```
// or
```

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
```

**If you are using ES modules, then you should do as:**

```
import { merge } from "webpack-merge"
```

Answer (score 4):

I use a ES6 webpack config, so I use webpack-merge@4.2.1 ...

```
import merge from "webpack-merge"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also leverage merge by renaming it like below:

```js
const { merge: webpackMerge } = require("webpack-merge");
```

by this way you still using the same name of old api of the package!

Answer (score 0):

I have imported like below,

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
```

and used as

```
const mergedConfig = merge(config, customConfig);
```